# Is condition_a or condition_b and condition_c always equivalent to (condition_a or condition_b) and condition_c?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is `condition_a or condition_b and condition_c` always equivalent to `(condition_a or condition_b) and condition_c`?

Some of the people around me said they work samely but the others didn't agree because short-circuit happens in some cases. For example, if `condition_a` is True, `condition_a` is evaluated as True and the first one terminates but the second one doesn't.

Then, I experimented with them.

```
>>> (False or True) and True
True
>>> False or True and True
True
```

It seems like they work samely. If the short-circuit works, the second one should be False. I guess anyway the short-circuit evaluation works only between two conditions at once, so it means they are equivalent as `False or True` is evaluated first then the result of `False or True` and True is evaluated. Does it sound correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `and` has higher precedence than `or`. For example,

```
>>> True or False and False
True
>>> (True or False) and False
False
```

Section 6.17 of https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence
shows then precendence of operators.